# Python requests print used cipher for HTTPS

Tags: python, ssl, python-requests

I have developed a CherryPy REST service with SSL (TLSv1-TLSv1.2) and disabling ciphers and insecure protocols.

Now I have another piece of code using Python requests to connect to this service. I already have written an TLS HTTPAdapter and a request succeeds. I have only one problem:

I neither see what cipher was chosen on server side nor on client side. So in fact, I do not really know, if my security options took place. I could not find out how to get SSLSocket.cipher() from the builtin Python module called for CherryPy or requests.

Is there a simple way to get this information?

Here is an example:

```
import requests

from requests.adapters import HTTPAdapter
from requests.packages.urllib3.poolmanager import PoolManager

class Tlsv1_2HttpAdapter(HTTPAdapter):
    """"Transport adapter" that allows us to use TLSv1.2"""

    def init_poolmanager(self, connections, maxsize, block=False):
        self.poolmanager = PoolManager(
            num_pools=connections, maxsize=maxsize,
            block=block, ssl_version=ssl.PROTOCOL_TLSv1_2)

con = "https://{}:{}".format(host, port)

tls = Tlsv1_2HttpAdapter()

try:
    s = requests.Session()
    s.mount(con, tls)
    r = s.get(con)
except requests.exceptions.SSLError as e:
    print(e, file=sys.stderr)
    sys.exit(1)
```

I want something like: print("Cipher used: {}".format(foo.cipher()))

Many thanks in advance for your help

Comment: If it's just to make sure the right thing is happening, I'd simply launch [Wireshark](https://www.wireshark.org/) and snoop on the connection.  It will tell you the name of the cipher used.

Comment: Is there no Python option? I tried wireshark, but I do not know how to call it. If I only listen on an interface for a port, I see no information concerning TLS: tshark -i eth0 port 8443

Comment: There most certainly is a Python option, but I don't know it (and I don't have time to look it up).  I usually use the GUI for Wireshark, which is rather self-explanatory.  You just click start to start capturing, run your program, and then look at the captured packages.  If you don't define any filters, there might be some junk in your capture log, but it should be easy to spot the relevant packets.  The handshake packet contains information on the Cipher used.

Answer (score 3):

As a temporary solution for testing, the code below prints out the cipher suite (position 0) and protocol (position 1) like that:

```
('ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384', 'TLSv1/SSLv3', 256)
```

Python 2.7 (tested):

```
from httplib import HTTPConnection


def request(self, method, url, body=None, headers={}):
    self._send_request(method, url, body, headers)
    print(self.sock.cipher())

HTTPConnection.request = request
```

Python 3 ([tested on v3.8.9 by comment below](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36102451/50953321?#comment121371035_50953321)):

```
from http.client import HTTPConnection


def request(self, method, url, body=None, headers={}, *,
            encode_chunked=False):
    self._send_request(method, url, body, headers, encode_chunked)
    print(self.sock.cipher())

HTTPConnection.request = request
```

This is monkey patching the `request()` method for the only reason of adding the print statement. You can replace the print function by a debug logger if you want more control over the output.

Import or paste this snippet at the beginning of your code so that it can monkey patch the method as early as possible.

Comment: FYI, tested in Python 3.8.9 and it works.